# Which option of bonding multiple strands from Cat5 pick up the lowest level of EMI?

Tags: microcontroller, dc, emi-filtering

**Caviat**

I am not an EE major, nor have I had the opportunity to study general EE principles. At best, I could be considered a weekend hobbyist. This is my first time posting to this SE site.

**Some background:**

I have a microcontroller that I have programmed to monitor for change in state on a circuit. A good analogy would be a alarm circuit. When there is a change in the state, I will perform some action. I have this circuit set up as a working prototype. I am planning on using Cat5 for the loop of cable for the monitored circuit. The area in which the controller and circuit will eventually be placed has the potential to be a somewhat noisy environment from an EMI perspective.

**Okay, what is the question then?**

If the eight strands in the Cat5 were to be bonded together into two legs to carry low mA DC current, is there any advantage to which 4 strands are connected from the perspective of lowering EMI that is picked up by the wire and transmitted back to the microcontroller?

For reference the pinout for Cat5 cable is as follows:
[image: Cat5 Pinout Diagram]

Each white-dash wire and the solid colored wire of the same color are a twisted pair.

Comment: I think you mean EMI.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the catch. The post is corrected now.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet would be to bond 1 wire from each twisted pair together; so to keep it simple, bond the 4 dashed wires together, and the 4 solid wires together.

From our good friends at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twisted_pair):

*"Twisted pair cabling is a type of wiring in which two conductors of a single circuit are twisted together for the purposes of canceling out electromagnetic interference (EMI) from external sources"*

So, each solid/dashed pair should cancel each other out.

Answer (score 0):

Keep your CAT5 away from 117VAC power wiring. The spikes, magnetic spikes, from microwave ovens, will induce this level of interference:

100 amps in 30 nanoseconds; this rate of change of current comes from peak currents versus average current in  diode rectifiers at the 2,000 volt level to power the magnetron. The voltage dV/dT is 2,000 volt * 377 radians/second = 750,000 volts per second into the rectifier diode(s). If one diode, with 0.026 volts delta_V providing 2.718X more current thru the exponential diode junction,
the turn on time will be 0.026 / 750,000 or approximately 30 hanoseconds.

Assuming loop area of 1 square meter (your CAT5 loop) and distance of 1 meter,
the induced voltage (probably occurring inside your wall) will be

Vinduce = 2e-7 * Area/Distance * dI/dT

Vinduce = 2e-7 Henry/meter * 1meter^2/1meter * 3 GegaAmps/second

Vinduce = 2e-7 * 3 E+9 = 6 e+2 = 600 volts

600 volts induced into your loop, because the microwave oven is in use.

Comment: I am a little lost in the details of your answer. Can you help with with some practical guidelines? What do you mean by keep them away from each other? How far away from the wire electric wire? Don't run them side-by-side for yards and yards? Don't have them cross paths at all?